# (Universal) Basic Income as a type of insurance

Tags: capitalism

I was thinking about UBI a lot and I can see that it has many up and down sides. What I would like to know is if there is a concept like UBI, which is not paid by the government through taxes, but rather a voluntarily kind of insurance where you agree to pay back a percentage of your future income or something. It could also be seen as some kind of loan. Are there any concepts like these? Are there any economic advantages between a voluntary, private UBI compared to a "forced" state-funded one?

Comment: This sounds a lot like employment insurance (but mandatory). Every employed individual pays a percentage of their income (the premium) to insure against the risk of losing their job. In such a situation the insured has a smoother stream of income across employed and unemployed periods. What risk would this hypothetical UBI be insuring against?